# php/html invoice table using mysql data combining all sales of a person into one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I have a mysql table that contains invoice info for my members.

### invoice table

```
memberid | item | amount
------------------------
mem1     | book | 100.00
mem1     | lamp | 50.00
mem2     | desk | 200.00
mem1     | pen  | 1.00
```

I would like to combine all of the rows of a specific memberid into a single row (either in a temporary mysql table or even just dump it into an html table for viewing)

### example - new invoice table

```
memberid | item1 | amount1 | item2 | amount2 | item3 | amount3 
---------------------------------------------------------------
mem1     | book  | 100.00  | lamp  | 50.00   | pen   | 1.00
mem2     | desk  | 200.00  | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | NULL</pre>
```

I would need this new table to add the new item and amount column ***dynamically*** as the number of times a member buys an item is unknown. so lets say mem1 buys another item, this new table would have to append 2 more columns (**item4, amount4**).

Comment: Tables are designed to have static structure, why do you need dynamic?

Comment: There is a limit to the number of columns a table can have - you really don't want to have to pull out each column value either...

Comment: it's best to do the pivoting outside MySQL, e.g. in php read the rows into an array, stop when the `memberid` changes and output that in a row. clear the array, read all the values for the the next series of `memberid` and keep on looping until done.

Comment: As to the column limit, i dont think it would be a major issue, the most purchases iv seen so far is 5 or 6 from a single member. Even if that number grows to 100 or 200 the table will only have 200 to 400 columns which is much lower than the 4000+ hard limit on tables.

Comment: i need this structure because the accounting dept needs the data in this format and i wanted to see if i can generate this for them straight on the website backend. If it is not possible to do this using web code i guess i'll just hand them off a spreadsheet of the data as is and they can sort and make a pivot table in excel or something. but it would be great if i can do accomplish this for them right on the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to pivot a table in MySQL, but you do have a build-in pivot function: `GROUP_CONCAT`
Here's my suggestion.

The idea is to build a table in html, using the tags for start table etc.

Here's what a table looks like in html source.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>A1</td> <td>B1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A2</td> <td>B2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here's the ascii art of the output

```
+--------+--------+
| A1     | B1     |
+--------+--------+
| A2     | B2     |
+--------+--------+
```

You can build this using group concat

```
SELECT 
  concat('<tr><td>',s.member_id,'</td>'
         ,group_concat(s.itempair SEPARATOR '')
         ,'</tr>') as row
  FROM (
    SELECT member_id, concat('<td>',item,'</td><td>',amount,'</td>') as itempair
    FROM invoice ORDER BY member_id, item ) s
  GROUP BY s.member_id;
```

Now you can just start the table by echoing a `<table border = "1">` tag,
Echoing all the `row`s from the select
and finally echoing a `</table>` tag.

For more info on group_concat
see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Good luck with the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with a foreign key to a user, a foreign key to a product, and a foreign key to an invoice. Create separate tables for products, users, and invoices. Then, use joining to combine all that information together.

Comment: I know i'm asking alot... but would be able to gimme a quick example of what the code would be to join the info together after the seperate tables are made the way you suggested?